# Can I enter the UK the day before the expiry date of my visa?

Tags: visas, uk

We are arriving UK on 29th Apr and visa expires on 30th Apr. Our return date is 10th MAY. Will they allow us entry ? Is the expiry date like enter UK before 30th Apr or Expires on that day ?

Answer (score 4):

My answer (which I simply deleted) was completely wrong. Let's try with a source, now :)

[Official source](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/extend-your-visa):

> Once you’ve applied you can stay in the UK until you’ve been given a decision, as long as you applied before your last visa expired.

So: if your last visa expired and you didn't yet apply for a visa extension you can not stay.

Some unofficial sources. http://www.passportvisasexpress.com/visa_services/united_kingdom/country_information/after_visa_issuance

> What is the latest date that I can arrive in the UK with my visa?
>
> The expiry date will be shown on the visa, but remember that this is also the last day on which you are permitted to stay in the UK.

http://www.ukpermits.com/visa-types/uk-visitors-visas

> Please note that upon the expiry of your visa, you are required to leave the UK.