# Traveling to UK on visit visa as a Syrian citizen?

Tags: visas, uk, london, syrian-citizens

I have a question regarding my trip to London, as I have a visit visa that will expire on September 5th.
And I am planning the trip on September 1st but would it be a problem to leave London for a few days after my visa expires ?
By the way I have a Syrian passport but I am a full time residence of Dubai.
I have a multiple entry visit visa than expires on the 5th and am planning my trip from the 1st to the 10th.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I enter the UK the day before the expiry date of my visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/can-i-enter-the-uk-the-day-before-the-expiry-date-of-my-visa)

Comment: Overstaying can ruin your next visa chances.

Comment: Your existing visa ends on the 5th, so you would be required to leave by midnight of the 5th. Any time you remain in the UK beyond that point will be considered an overstay, and you may have to face legal consequences. The only way to stay the full duration you desire (1st-10th) will be to apply for and be granted either an extension to your existing or a completely new visa covering the desired period.

Comment: Not a duplicate, this one addresses a different rule.

Answer (score 5):

When you arrive in the UK, you will speak with an Immigration Officer and at that time you can ask him/her to vary your 'end date'.  They can if they want, but do not have to do it and most of the time they not do it.

This is addressed in Paragraph 31A of the Immigration Rules, which states...

> Where a person has arrived in the United Kingdom with leave to enter
>   or remain in the United Kingdom which is in force but was given to him
>   before his arrival, he may apply, on arrival at the port of entry in
>   the United Kingdom, for variation of that leave. An Immigration
>   Officer acting on behalf of the Secretary of State may vary the leave
>   at the port of entry but is not obliged to consider an application for
>   variation made at the port of entry. If an Immigration Officer acting
>   on behalf of the Secretary of State has declined to consider an
>   application for variation of leave at a port of entry but the leave
>   has not been cancelled under paragraph 2A(8) of Schedule 2 to the
>   Immigration Act 1971, the person seeking variation should apply to the
>   Home Office under paragraph 32.

Source:  https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/420595/Immigration_rules_part_1_master_20150406_v1_final.pdf

...or in plain English:  `You can try to get a variation, but they do not have to grant it if they do not want to`.  If they agree, they will know what to do and what to put in your passport.  If they refuse, your original 'end date' must be observed.

A refusal at port to *vary* leave does not create a pejorative immigration history.  But a port side *cancellation* of leave does.

Needless to say, your request should be well supported by documents along with a reasonable explanation.  Outcomes may also be heavily influenced by [personal impact](http://www.theperformancecoach.com/blog/2011/9/5/what-is-personal-impact.html) and articulation skills, but once they say they will not do it, the best advice is to let it go.

**Adding...**

The Home Secretary issued a [Ministerial Authorisation affecting Syrian nationals](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201314/cmhansrd/cm140325/wmstext/140325m0001.htm) on 27 Feb 2015 and this is still in force.  You may be able to benefit from it.  Or may not.

> I have agreed a ministerial authorisation (Equality (Syria—Entry
>   clearance outside the immigration rules) Authorisation 2014) to allow
>   differentiation in favour of Syrian nationals whom we want to bring to
>   the UK under the VPR scheme.

Plus a new rule for Syrians came in to effect in March 2015...

> A Statement of Changes to the Immigration Rules HC 1116 was published
>   on 16 March
>   2015. These changes specifically affect Syrian nationals who are travelling through the UK on certain types of visit visas for entry to
>   United States of America.

More info at [Immigration Law Practitioners Association](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/resources.php/30885/information-sheet_-syrian-nationals-new-immigration-rules)